# Missing dependencies for HttpServletRequest with Jersey

Tags: jersey

I have a Standalone Jersey server running at the beginning of my JunitTest. I'm testing if my [JaxRS controller](https://github.com/nicolas-zozol/robusta-web-library/blob/master/robusta/library/src/main/java/com/robustaweb/library/rest/controller/implementation/JaxRsResourceController.java) works, as well as my custom HttpClient. Please note that I've always been able to use this JaxRsResourceController embedded in glassfish.

Here is the JaxRsController (light version)

```
@Path("root")
public class JaxRsResourceController implements
        ResourceController<HttpServletRequest> {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @GET
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("Uri is "+this.context.getBaseUri().toString());
        return "Hello "+peoples;
    }

}
```

I have no problem with the client, but when I start the server, I have :

```
GRAVE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest com.robustaweb.library.rest.controller.implementation.JaxRsResourceController.request
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse com.robustaweb.library.rest.controller.implementation.JaxRsResourceController.response

    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:172)
    at com.robustaweb.library.rest.server.JerseyServer.startServer(JerseyServer.java:44)
```

Basically it says that at the @Context injection time, there is no dependency on the HttpServletRequest.
However if I remove the @Context annotations on request and response, but keep it for `UriInfo context`, it's ok, and I can read the Uri.

I changed a few times the Maven pom wich is now to force the libs in:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not easy, but I found out. The thing is that in my JUnit test, I was creating the server like this :

```
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(url);
```

But that way, you create a lightweight container that does not have servlet containers, and so is the failure reason. So in order to have it all, I used the jersey-test-framework that allow to use the Grizzly web container (or even Embedded glassfish).

Here is the maven :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Unit test are using jersey server directly -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.test.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

Here is the JerseyServerTest : note that it extends JerseyTest

```
public class JerseyServerTest extends JerseyTest {

    protected String baseUri = "http://localhost:" + TestConstants.JERSEY_HTTP_PORT + "/";

    public JerseyServerTest() throws Exception {
        super("com.robustaweb.library.rest.controller");

        /*
        It's possible to NOT call the super() but to manually do :
        1)  ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor()
                .setRootResourcePackageName(resourcePackageName) // resource packages
                .setContextPath(contextPath) //context of app
                .setServletPath(servletPath); // context of spi servlet
        2)setupTestEnvironment(appDescriptor);
         */
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldRequest() {
        SunRestClient client = new SunRestClient(baseUri + "root");
        String result = client.GET("", null);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteRequest() {
        SunRestClient client = new SunRestClient(baseUri + "root");
        String result = client.DELETE("john", null);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

And finally the Resource file, that contains @GET and @DELETE

```
@Path("root")
public class JaxRsController extends JaxRsResourceController{

    List<String> peoples = new ArrayList<String>();

    @GET
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("Uri is "+getUri());
        return "Hello "+peoples;
    }   

    @DELETE
    @Path("{name}")
    public String deletePeople(@PathParam("name") String name){
        System.out.println("deleting "+name);
        this.peoples.remove(name);
        return String.valueOf(peoples.size());
    }
}
```

And now it works !
I had some help in [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_makes_it), and there is a [small chapter on the documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). Beeing able to attach the source code of the Jersey framework really helped, so thantks to IntelliJ also.

Answer (score 1):

servlet dependencies were separated to another module, try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.

Comment: It didn't do the job for me. Here is my answer.